# Ext.Net Rtl="true"

Tags: extjs, ext.net

according to ExtJS you can use rtl:true for mirroring right to left

does Ext.Net 2.1 support this ?

How to use this property with Ext.Net ?

**UPDATE**
As answered , it's not yet supported but I found this css and js to be very useful

[mirror.css, mirror.js](http://behrang.github.com/extjs-mirror/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is first supported in ExtJS 4.2 and in none version before. I am not that familiar with Ext.Net but I doubt that it will be possible cause they are using the core too.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @sra, RTL support is being introduced in ExtJS 4.2, which is currently in Beta release. The current build of Ext.NET (2.2) in SVN includes the most recent Ext JS 4.2 Beta release. There are several samples in the Ext.NET 2.2 Examples Explorer which demonstrate the new RTL support.

The final release of Ext.NET 2.2 will include the final release of Ext JS 4.2.

Hope this helps.

Comment: When will the 2.2 version be released ?

Comment: Ext.NET 2.2 will be released immediately after the final public release of Ext JS 4.2.